# Topology is trivial if any continuous function is constant.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ has following property: any continuous map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to any topological space $Y$ is constant. Show that topology for $X$ is trivial.

Have anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the identity $id_X:X\rightarrow X$. If $X$ has more than one point, $id_X$ is not constant, hence not continuous (by the assumption). So by definition there exists an open $V\subset X$ such that $id_X^{-1}(V)$ is not open. But $id_X^{-1}(V)=V$ and $V$ is open, a contradiction.

Thus we must conclude that $X$ has only one point. (Obviously $X$ does have the trivial topology). So the question is true, but the only example of such a topological space is a space with one element.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a open $U \subset X$ that is not empty and not $X$. Consider the space $Y=\{0,1\}$ whith the following topology: the open sets are $Y,\emptyset, \{0\}$ and nothing else. Then the function $f:X \to Y$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0\qquad x \in U\\
1 \qquad \text{else} 
\end{cases}$$

is not constant and continous (check this).

Comment: $\{Y,\{0\}\}$ must also be in your topology.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I wrote the open sets are $Y,\emptyset,\{0\}$ or in other words $\tau=\{Y,\emptyset,\{0\}\}$.

Comment: The topology by definition is the collection of off unions of open sets declared for your space. So if $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and you say $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are open, then $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ is open as well.

Comment: And what would $Y \cup \{0\}$ be in this case?

Comment: What do you meant, what will it be? It is an open set as well by definition. You are missing a few open sets.

Comment: Ok, you are saying that the open sets I gave you are not a topology on $Y$. And I say that is not true. What you wrote is that if $U,V$ are open than $U\cup V$ is also open. But this is true for my sets. I suggest you check this again.

Comment: Ah, you're space is $Y = \{0,1\}$ I didn't see that. My apologies.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood : $Y\cup \left\{0\right\} =Y$ since $\left\{0\right\}\subset Y$. There is no problem with the definition of the topology

Comment: @MaikPickl : Nice example, it basically says the same as my answer. Note that your function is the constant zero function if $X$ contains only one element.

Comment: @Mathematician42 jep, I allready saw your answer. Also nice, i didn't notice that. You have my upvote. :)

Comment: Thanks, I was also trying something similar to your construction at first, but then I realized that the identity function is always continuous, which makes the condition Nikmort gives a bit weird. It is true however that if $X$ has the trivial topology and $Y$ the discrete topology, then any continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is constant. (and I gave an upvote as well :D )